# Correctly calculating parole day with python

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

Good evening! I'm a lawyer and I often have to calculate how long until sentenced people will be able to reach benefits, like parole.

It works like this:

First, I need to get some main variables, like the day that person started serving the sentence (the day he was arrested). This will be a base date for the first benefit. Lets say someone was arrested at 12 November 2014.

```
base_date = datetime.date(day=12, month=11, year=2014)
```

The second thing I have to do is to know what was the sentence for each crime (sometimes the person is convicted for more than one crime and, for each of them, there is a different calcule for the benefit. Let's say this person was convicted for two crimes:

- For the first crime (which is a more serious crime), he was sentenced for 7 years and 4 months in jail.
- For the second crime, he was sentenced for 4 years, 10 months and 20 days in jail.

In order to do that, I used this method and this is where I think my code fails. I believe these variables should be in a datetime method, or something like that.

`pena1_years, pena1_months, pena1_days = 7, 4, 0`

`pena2_years, pena2_months, pena2_days = 4, 10, 20`

Now, as the first crime is more serious, he will need to serve 2/5 of that sentence plus 1/6 of his second sentence to be able to reach his first benefit. The result of both should be added to base_date, in order to know when he will be able to reach the first benefit. I transformed everything into days.

```
pena1_total = int(((pena1_years * 365) + (pena1_months * 30) + (pena1_days)) / 5 * 2)
datedifference1 = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=pena1_total)
pena1_total = relativedelta(datetime.datetime.now(), datedifference1)
print("Pena 1: " + str(pena1_total.years) + "a, " + str(pena1_total.months) + "m, " + str(pena1_total.days) + "d.")
```

(Print returned this: Pena 1: 2a, 11m, 4d.)

```
pena2_total = int(((pena2_years * 365) + (pena2_months * 30) + (pena2_days)) / 6)
datedifference2 = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=pena2_total)
pena2_total = relativedelta(datetime.datetime.now(), datedifference2)
print("Pena 2: " + str(pena2_total.years) + "a, " + str(pena2_total.months) + "m, " + str(pena2_total.days) + "d.")
```

(Print returned this: Pena 2: 0a, 9m, 21d.)

After calculating the fractions for each crime, I'd need to sum both and then add to the base date. In this situation, this guy would have to serve 2 years, 11 months and 5 days for the first crime and 9 months and 23 days for the second one, in a total of 3 years, 8 months and 29 days before he can have his first benefit. However, I need to follow this rules (this is how the law says it must be calculated):

- Must use regular calendar (Gregorian);
- First, add up the years (2014 + 3 years = 2017);
- Then, add up the months (July 2018);
- Then, add up the days, but the first day he started serving must count (9 august 2018). It's important that the calendar is used when adding up the days, since the number of days in a month (and also depending on the year) may vary.

This is how I did it, but I'm not getting 9 august of 2018:

```
total = pena1_total + pena2_total
print("Total: " + str(total.years) + "a, " + str(total.months) + "m, " + str(total.days) + "d.")
```

(Print returned this: Total: 3a, 8m, 25d.)

```
data_semiaberto = data_base + relativedelta(days=+total.days, months=+total.months, years=+total.years)
print("Data para o semiaberto: " + str(data_semiaberto))
```

(Print returned this: Data para o semiaberto: 2018-08-06)

Then, the date for the first benefit will be the base date for his parole. He will need to serve another 2/5 of the remaining sentence for the first crime and 1/6 for the remaining sentence for the second crime. For this, I'd need to subtract what he served so far from the total sentence for each crime. However, I'm stuck here.

Here is the full code:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

data_base = datetime.date(day=12, month=11, year=2014)
pena1_years, pena1_months, pena1_days = 7, 4, 0
pena2_years, pena2_months, pena2_days = 4, 10, 20

def calculadora():
    # Fraction of the first sentence
    pena1_total = int(((pena1_years * 365) + (pena1_months * 30) + (pena1_days)) / 5 * 2)
    datedifference1 = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=pena1_total)
    pena1_total = relativedelta(datetime.datetime.now(), datedifference1)
    print("Pena 1: " + str(pena1_total.years) + "a, " + str(pena1_total.months) + "m, " + str(pena1_total.days) + "d.")

    # Fraction of the second sentence
    pena2_total = int(((pena2_years * 365) + (pena2_months * 30) + (pena2_days)) / 6)
    datedifference2 = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=pena2_total)
    pena2_total = relativedelta(datetime.datetime.now(), datedifference2)
    print("Pena 2: " + str(pena2_total.years) + "a, " + str(pena2_total.months) + "m, " + str(pena2_total.days) + "d.")

    # Fraction total
    total = pena1_total + pena2_total
    print("Total: " + str(total.years) + "a, " + str(total.months) + "m, " + str(total.days) + "d.")


    # Date of the first benefit.
    data_semiaberto = data_base + relativedelta(days=+total.days, months=+total.months, years=+total.years)
    print("Data para o semiaberto: " + str(data_semiaberto))
calculadora()
```

Could someone help me please? It'd save me a lot of time during work.

Comment: You wrote _Must use regular calendar (Gregorian)_ and _Then, add up the days, but the first day he started serving must count (9 august 2018). It's important that the calendar is used when adding up the days, since the number of days in a month (and also depending on the year) may vary._ Are there any adjustments made for those variations in the number of days in a month and days in a year? For example, if I am sentenced to 1 year in prison on a leap year, do I only spend 364 days incarcerated, instead of the 365 that I would spend on a "regular" year?

Comment: ^ Oops, I meant of course 366 days, not 364.

Comment: The way the law tells to count 1 year is like this: you were arrested today (April 23 2020 at 11pm). You should be released at April 22 2021 same time (first day counts as a whole day). If you must serve only 2 months and you were arrested at April 23 2020 at 11pm, you should be released at June 22 same time. In the end, just substract 1 day in all circunstances.

Comment: Another interesting information (doesn't matter for the purpose of this script) is that when someone is sentenced in days, you will count 1 by 1 in the calendar. However, I've never seen someone being sentenced to 365 days, for instance. In that case, you would have to count day by day. So, regular calendar always matters when you're counting days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading Rickey's and Sathish's answer, I've came out with a solution. It's returning the correct dates.

Still need to finish the code to automate any circumstance.

I'm not sure if I can post the [GitHub](https://github.com/andreluisos/direito/blob/master/progregime.py) here. So, here's the code.

```
import datetime, math
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

# Método dias para anos, meses e dias.
def days_to_ymd(days):
    global days_to_ymd_result
    years = days // 365
    months = (days % 365) // 30
    days = (days % 365) % 30
    days_to_ymd_result = relativedelta(years=+years, months=+months, days=+days)
    return days_to_ymd_result

# Método anos, meses e dias para dias.
def ymd_to_days(years, months, days):
    global ymd_to_days_result
    ymd_to_days_result = (years * 365) + (months * 30) + days
    return ymd_to_days_result

# Método frações de dias.
def frac(days, frac):
    global frac_result
    frac_result = math.ceil(days * frac)
    return frac_result

# Data base.
data_base = datetime.date(day=12, month=11, year=2014)
print("Data base: " + data_base.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))

# Informações sobre as penas.
pena1 = relativedelta(years=+7, months=+4, days=+0)
pena1_totaldays = ymd_to_days(years=pena1.years, months=pena1.months, days=pena1.days)
pena2 = relativedelta(years=+4, months=+10, days=+20)
pena2_totaldays = ymd_to_days(years=pena2.years, months=pena2.months, days=pena2.days)
pena_total = pena1 + pena2
pena_total_days = ymd_to_days(years=pena_total.years, months=pena_total.months, days=pena_total.days)
print("Pena 1: " + str(pena1.years) + "a, " + str(pena1.months) + "m, " + str(pena1.days) + "d (" + str(pena1_totaldays) + " dias).")
print("Pena 2: " + str(pena2.years) + "a, " + str(pena2.months) + "m, " + str(pena2.days) + "d (" + str(pena2_totaldays) + " dias).")
print("Pena total: " + str(pena_total.years) + "a, " + str(pena_total.months) + "m, " + str(pena_total.days) + "d (" + str(pena_total_days) + " dias).")

# Frações de pena.
pena1_frac = frac(days=pena1_totaldays, frac=2/5)
pena2_frac = frac(days=pena2_totaldays, frac=1/6)
frac_total_days = pena1_frac + pena2_frac - 72
frac_total = days_to_ymd(frac_total_days)
print("2/5 de " + str(pena1.years) + "a, " + str(pena1.months) + "m, " + str(pena1.days) + "d (" + str(pena1_totaldays) + " dias): " + str(days_to_ymd(pena1_frac).years) + "a, " + str(days_to_ymd(pena1_frac).months) + "m, " + str(days_to_ymd(pena1_frac).days) + "d (" + str(pena1_frac) + " dias).")
print("1/6 de " + str(pena2.years) + "a, " + str(pena2.months) + "m, " + str(pena2.days) + "d (" + str(pena2_totaldays) + " dias): " + str(days_to_ymd(pena2_frac).years) + "a, " + str(days_to_ymd(pena2_frac).months) + "m, " + str(days_to_ymd(pena2_frac).days) + "d (" + str(pena2_frac) + " dias).")
print("Total a ser cumprido: " + str(frac_total.years) + "a, " + str(frac_total.months) + "m, " + str(frac_total.days) + "d (" + str(frac_total_days) + " dias).")

# Semiaberto.
data_semiaberto = data_base + (relativedelta(years=+frac_total.years, months=+frac_total.months, days=+(frac_total.days - 1))) # -1 = Inclui o dia do começo (art. 10, CP).
print("Data prevista para o regime semiaberto: " + str(data_semiaberto.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")))

# Pena restante.
pena1_restante_days = pena1_totaldays - pena1_frac
pena2_restante_days = pena2_totaldays - pena2_frac
pena_restante_total_days = pena1_restante_days + pena2_restante_days
pena1_restante = days_to_ymd(pena1_restante_days)
pena2_restante = days_to_ymd(pena2_restante_days)
pena_restante = days_to_ymd(pena_restante_total_days)
print("Pena 1 restante: " + str(pena1_restante.years) + "a, " + str(pena1_restante.months) + "m, " + str(pena1_restante.days) + "d (" + str(pena1_restante_days) + " dias).")
print("Pena 2 restante: " + str(pena2_restante.years) + "a, " + str(pena2_restante.months) + "m, " + str(pena2_restante.days) + "d (" + str(pena2_restante_days) + " dias).")
print("Pena total restante: " + str(pena_restante.years) + "a, " + str(pena_restante.months) + "m, " + str(pena_restante.days) + "d (" + str(pena_restante_total_days) + " dias).")

# Frações da pena.
pena1_frac = frac(days=pena1_restante_days, frac=2/5)
pena2_frac = frac(days=pena2_restante_days, frac=1/6)
frac_total_days = (pena1_frac + pena2_frac)
frac_total = days_to_ymd(frac_total_days)
print("2/5 de " + str(pena1_restante.years) + "a, " + str(pena1_restante.months) + "m, " + str(pena1_restante.days) + "d (" + str(pena1_restante_days) + " dias): " + str(days_to_ymd(pena1_frac).years) + "a, " + str(days_to_ymd(pena1_frac).months) + "m, " + str(days_to_ymd(pena1_frac).days) + "d (" + str(pena1_frac) + " dias).")
print("1/6 de " + str(pena2_restante.years) + "a, " + str(pena2_restante.months) + "m, " + str(pena2_restante.days) + "d (" + str(pena2_restante_days) + " dias): " + str(days_to_ymd(pena2_frac).years) + "a, " + str(days_to_ymd(pena2_frac).months) + "m, " + str(days_to_ymd(pena2_frac).days) + "d (" + str(pena2_frac) + " dias).")
print("Total a ser cumprido: " + str(frac_total.years) + "a, " + str(frac_total.months) + "m, " + str(frac_total.days) + "d (" + str(frac_total_days) + " dias).")

# Aberto.
data_aberto = data_semiaberto + (relativedelta(years=+frac_total.years, months=+frac_total.months, days=+(frac_total.days - 1))) # -1 = Inclui o dia do começo (art. 10, CP).
print("Data prevista para o regime aberto: " + str(data_aberto.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the code below, it calculates the number of days first and then subtract the days for each benefits and prints the date for the next benefit avail date.

To consider the leap years and number of days in each month, its better to calculate the total number of days and built the logic on it.

Output will print the details of the each benefit and finally shows the total number of days spent together.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

data_base = datetime.date(day=12, month=11, year=2014)
pena1_years, pena1_months, pena1_days = 7, 4, 0
pena2_years, pena2_months, pena2_days = 4, 10, 20
total_days_spent = 0

def calculadora():
    # Calculate the end date and total number of days for the first crime
    pena1_end_date = data_base + relativedelta(years=+pena1_years, months=+pena1_months, days=+pena1_days)
    pena1_reamining_days = (pena1_end_date - data_base).days

    # Calculate the end date and total number of days for the second crime
    pena2_end_date = data_base + relativedelta(years=+pena2_years, months=+pena2_months, days=+pena2_days)
    pena2_reamining_days = (pena2_end_date - data_base).days

    benefit_count=1
    while pena1_reamining_days > 0 or pena2_reamining_days > 0:
        #count the minumum number of days for both the crimes
        pena1_minimum_days = round(pena1_reamining_days / 5 * 2)
        if pena1_minimum_days == 0 and pena1_reamining_days > 0:
            pena1_minimum_days = pena1_reamining_days
        pena1_reamining_days -= pena1_minimum_days
        print(f"Minimum no of days to spent in the first crime for the {benefit_count} benefit is {pena1_minimum_days} ")

        pena2_minimum_days = round(pena2_reamining_days / 6)
        if pena2_minimum_days == 0 and pena2_reamining_days > 0:
            pena2_minimum_days = pena2_reamining_days
        pena2_reamining_days -= pena2_minimum_days
        print(f"Minimum no of days to spent in the second crime for the {benefit_count} benefit is {pena2_minimum_days} ")

        total = pena1_minimum_days + pena2_minimum_days
        global total_days_spent
        total_days_spent += total
        print(f"Total no of days to spent for the {benefit_count} benefit {total} ")

        date_next_benefit = data_base + relativedelta(days=+total)
        print(f"{benefit_count} benefit day to avail after {date_next_benefit}")

        benefit_count+=1

calculadora()
print(f"Total number of days spent for both the crime is {total_days_spent}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm here to learn I thought I'd take a shot at this.  This code still needs some work, but I think it's a good start.  My feelings won't be hurt if you discard it.  We can add features as needed if you want to use it.

```
import datetime as dt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta as rdelta


class Sentence:

    release_date = None

    def __init__(self, year=1970, month=1, day=1):
        """Create a new instance with the date of the arrest,
        default is set to the unix epoch...hehehe"""
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        self.day = day
        self.base_date = dt.date(self.year, self.month, self.day)
        self.arrest_date = dt.date(self.year, self.month, self.day)

    def basedate(self):
        """Returns the basedate/arrest date"""
        return self.arrest_date

    def penalty(self, years=0, months=0, days=0):
        """Each time the penalty method is call it accumulates
        the length of the sentence.  Returns release date."""
        self.years = years
        self.months = months
        self.days = days

        if Sentence.release_date is None:
            Sentence.release_date = (self.base_date +
                                     rdelta(years=self.years,
                                            months=self.months,
                                            days=self.days))
        else:
            Sentence.release_date = (Sentence.release_date +
                                     rdelta(years=self.years,
                                            months=self.months,
                                            days=self.days))

        return Sentence.release_date - rdelta(days=1)

    def remaining(self):
        """Returns a tuple of years, months, days remaining of the
        sentence"""
        self.y_remaining = rdelta(Sentence.release_date, dt.date.today()).years
        self.m_remaining = rdelta(Sentence.release_date,
                                  dt.date.today()).months
        self.d_remaining = rdelta(Sentence.release_date, dt.date.today()).days

        return self.y_remaining, self.m_remaining, self.d_remaining


s1 = Sentence(2014, 11, 12)
print(f'Arreset Date: {"":>31}{s1.basedate()}')
print(f'Release Date after 1st sentence: {"":>12}{s1.penalty(7, 4, 0)}')
print(f'Release Date after 2nd sentence: {"":>12}{s1.penalty(4, 10, 20)}')
# print(f'Release Date after 2nd sentence: {"":>12}{s1.penalty(1, 2, 5)}')
print(f'Time remaining on sentence as of {dt.date.today()}: '
      f'{s1.remaining()[0]} years, {s1.remaining()[1]} months, '
      f'{s1.remaining()[2]} days')

# Output
# Arreset Date:                                2014-11-12
# Release Date after 1st sentence:             2022-03-11
# Release Date after 2nd sentence:             2027-01-31
# Time remaining on sentence as of 2020-04-24: 6 years, 9 months, 8 days
```